# How to dynamically add items to a list using a CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

Sorry if this is kind of a stupid question but I have been basically going in circles trying to figure out how to do this for some reason.

I have an ArrayList of contacts (with two parameters, name and phone number) that is populated from an SQL database using a `ContentProvider`. The ArrayList is populated using a `CursorAdapter` and then displayed in the UI. I want the user to be able to dynamically add items to the list of contacts.

In the CursorAdapter, two list item types are defined in `bindView()` and `newView()`. The first type consists of two EditTexts, one for name and one for phone number. The second type consists of two TextViews, for name and phone number.

Basically, this is what I want to happen:

1. The user presses a button that says "Add Contact" and a new list item of type EditText is dynamically added to the list.
2. The user fills in the contact information and then presses a button that says "Save Contact." When this button is pressed, the list item of type EditText is converted to a list item of type TextView and is added to the ArrayList and displayed with the other contacts.

I am pretty sure I know how to do at least part of the second thing, something along the lines of this:

```
contactsName = nameEditText.getText().toString();
contactsNumber = numberEditText.getText().toString();
contacts.add(new ContactsObject(contactsName, contactsNumber));
contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However what I am having trouble with is the first thing. How do I convert between the two different view types? How do I tell the adapter to create a list item of a certain type (EditText), and then to convert it to the other type (TextView)?

Answer (score 0):

Once the database is updated with the new data inserted (or removed or updated), for which you should definitely use CursorLoader, call method swapCursor(Cursor cursor) on your CursorAdapter subclass object. Checking that the adapter is not null, of course.

That will replace the cursor object used by your adapter and notify of set changes, redrawing all views.

Comment: Hi, I am still confused about this whole Cursor thing. a) Isn't the CursorLoader just used to query the existing database, not insert? I am looking at the CursorLoader methods and none of them seem to be about insertion. b) How do I initially specify whether a list item should be of type EditText or TextView? c) So when I use swapCursor I should swap out the old Cursor with the data type EditText, and swap in a new Cursor with data type TextView? Also why does swapCursor return the old cursor?